# Порядковая сортировка в словаре python СРОЧНО!

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

У меня есть python словарь с данными, мне нужно рассортировать этот словарь по значению из ключа STATUS, а именно сделать так, чтобы записи были последовательно данным из ключа:

1. CHECKED
2. DONE
3. REJECTED

Одна из проблемм с которой я столкнулся это невозможность переставить данные в нужном мне порядке.

```
{
'kfe': {'WRITE-KEY': 'kfe', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'tfP', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': 'none', 'STATUS': 'CHECKED', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'none', 'MESSAGE-ID': 0},

'zrq': {'WRITE-KEY': 'zrq', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'Tex', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '00:14:26 | 19-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'REJECTED', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'Вооввлвд', 'MESSAGE-ID': 35114},

'2rx': {'WRITE-KEY': '2rx', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': '0LU', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '23:15:56 | 18-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': '', 'MESSAGE-ID': 34970},

'jwV': {'WRITE-KEY': 'jwV', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'SAd', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '23:14:12 | 18-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': '', 'MESSAGE-ID': 34945},

'ucB': {'WRITE-KEY': 'ucB', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'Fdq', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '00:14:14 | 19-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'Ушшвшв', 'MESSAGE-ID': 35103}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если порядок аргументов у Вас именно такой, то можно просто отсортировать поле `STATUS` подсловарей в алфавитном порядке таким образом:

```py
d = {
'kfe': {'WRITE-KEY': 'kfe', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'tfP', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': 'none', 'STATUS': 'CHECKED', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'none', 'MESSAGE-ID': 0},
'zrq': {'WRITE-KEY': 'zrq', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'Tex', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '00:14:26 | 19-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'REJECTED', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'Вооввлвд', 'MESSAGE-ID': 35114},
'2rx': {'WRITE-KEY': '2rx', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': '0LU', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '23:15:56 | 18-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': '', 'MESSAGE-ID': 34970},
'jwV': {'WRITE-KEY': 'jwV', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'SAd', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '23:14:12 | 18-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': '', 'MESSAGE-ID': 34945},
'ucB': {'WRITE-KEY': 'ucB', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'Fdq', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '00:14:14 | 19-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'Ушшвшв', 'MESSAGE-ID': 35103}
}

sort_dict = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['STATUS']))
print(sort_dict)

--------
{
'kfe': {'WRITE-KEY': 'kfe', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'tfP', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': 'none', 'STATUS': 'CHECKED', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'none', 'MESSAGE-ID': 0},
'2rx': {'WRITE-KEY': '2rx', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': '0LU', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '23:15:56 | 18-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': '', 'MESSAGE-ID': 34970}, 
'jwV': {'WRITE-KEY': 'jwV', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'SAd', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '23:14:12 | 18-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': '', 'MESSAGE-ID': 34945}, 
'ucB': {'WRITE-KEY': 'ucB', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'Fdq', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '00:14:14 | 19-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'Ушшвшв', 'MESSAGE-ID': 35103}, 
'zrq': {'WRITE-KEY': 'zrq', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'Tex', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '00:14:26 | 19-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'REJECTED', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'Вооввлвд', 'MESSAGE-ID': 35114}
}
```

Пояснение: сначала берутся все пары "ключ-значение" словарей (благодаря `d.items()`), затем они сортируются по ключу лямбда-функции `lambda item: item[1]['STATUS']` — она берёт поле 'STATUS' значений подсловарей и сортирует последние именно по этому полю. Далее отсортированный полученный список становится словарём, который и отправляется на вывод. Вроде бы так

Comment: а есть существенная разница?)

Comment: @ДимаВиноградов да я увидел Ваш ответ уже после того, как отправил свой. Ещё я много времени потратил на расписывание, так что решил, что добру лучше не пропадать)

Comment: об этом я и говорил)

Answer (score 3):

```
your_dict = {
'kfe': {'WRITE-KEY': 'kfe', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'tfP', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': 'none', 'STATUS': 'CHECKED', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'none', 'MESSAGE-ID': 0},

'zrq': {'WRITE-KEY': 'zrq', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'Tex', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '00:14:26 | 19-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'REJECTED', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'Вооввлвд', 'MESSAGE-ID': 35114},

'2rx': {'WRITE-KEY': '2rx', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': '0LU', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '23:15:56 | 18-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': '', 'MESSAGE-ID': 34970},

'jwV': {'WRITE-KEY': 'jwV', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'SAd', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '23:14:12 | 18-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': '', 'MESSAGE-ID': 34945},

'ucB': {'WRITE-KEY': 'ucB', 'USER-ID': 639141904, 'WHO-WROTE': 'Jn<', 'TASK-KEY': 'Fdq', 'TIME-DATE-RECORDING': '00:14:14 | 19-01-2022', 'STATUS': 'DONE', 'ATTACHED-TEXT': 'Ушшвшв', 'MESSAGE-ID': 35103}
}
print(sorted(your_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['STATUS']))
```